# Value not visible in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new with WPF Mvvm.

A TextBox value is added to the ComboBox items, but if I select the ComboBox, the value is not visible in the ComboBox text.

**View**

```
<TextBlock Text="Tab Name" />
<TextBox Name="txtAddTabs" Text="{Binding SpecialAttractionModelObject.TabsCommaSeperate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<TextBlock Text="Select Tab Name" />
<ComboBox Name="tablist" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialAttractionModelObject.TabModelObj, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
          DisplayMemberPath ="TabName" 
          SelectedValuePath = "TabGid" 
          SelectedValue="{Binding TabGid}"
          />
```

Please anybody help to me.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted is incomplete - it doesn't match your description.

You have bound your ComboBox to a list of objects, so if you add anything to that list it has to be one of the same objects, correctly populated. Additionally `SpecialAttractionModelObject.TabModelObj` should be an ObservableCollection, otherwise new items being added won't automatically show up.

**However...** you said *"A TextBox value is added to the ComboBox items"*, which indicates that maybe you've gone about this the totally wrong way. If you bind the ComboBox to something (`ItemsSource="{Binding SpecialAttractionModelObject.TabModelObj...`) then you should not go a directly add a string to the ComboBox in another way - new values should be added to the bound item as mentioned in the first paragraph.